# BaseX gui or any other gui client to connect and manage a remote BaseX database?

Tags: basex

It seems BaseX gui works only for local databases. Is there any way to connect with and manage a remote BaseX server using BaseX gui? If not, is there any 3rd party solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer in BaseX [docs](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Main_Page). BaseX http server ('basexhttp' executable) provides box web based web based administration in this path (without changing the defaults) http://localhost:8984/dba . Documentation [here](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/DBA).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the BaseX GUI to connect to remote data by setting up a webdav server which will map your remote BaseX data folder like a local drive and then set the BaseX GUI Options/Preferences/General/Database Path to point to that drive.  Then you get all the nice BaseX GUI functionality - including visualizations - for your remote database.  I've done this and it works great.  Large databases and slow networks can hamper your experience.

Webdav Docs here:
http://docs.basex.org/wiki/WebDAV but I don't think they mention this setup configuration for the GUI connection.

I found this link to be helpful for webdav windows setup:
https://www.maketecheasier.com/map-webdav-drive-windows10/